# Неявный вызов процедур объявленых в пакете

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
Create or replace package body TEST_procedures_pkg as
PROCEDURE TEST_procedures_pkga                      IS
   object_name       VARCHAR2(255);

   CURSOR c1 IS(
                select procedure_name
                from user_procedures
                where object_name = 'PRODCEDURE');
BEGIN
   OPEN c1;
   LOOP
      FETCH c1 INTO object_name;
      --
   if c1%ISOPEN then
      object_name := 9999;
   end if; 
      --

      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(object_name);
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE c1;
END;


end TEST_procedures_pkg;

create or replace package TEST_procedures_pkg as
 --%Suite
 --%test
 procedure  TEST_procedures_pkga;
 --
end TEST_procedures_pkg;
```

Comment: А как вы её до сиих пор вызывали?

Comment: Mы называем каждый отдельно, Я хочу автоматизировать работу с циклом

Comment: Могли бы вы показать на примере: как сейчас, желаемое и ожидаемый результат.

Comment: PRODCEDURE.name1
PRODCEDURE.name2
PRODCEDURE.name3
 Я хочу, чтобы они вызывали все свои процедуры через цикл

Comment: если я добавлю процедуру, я должен записать ее в пакете, но я хочу пройти через цикл и сделать вызов, не добавляя его вручную

Comment: PRODCEDURE здесь имя пакета

Comment: Если предложеный ответ не совсем то, что требуется - напишите комментарий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно вызывать все процедуры объявленные в пакете динамически.

Объявим пакет:

```
create or replace package myProcedures as
    procedure execute;
    procedure proc1 (inParams varchar2, outParams out nocopy varchar2);
    procedure proc2 (inParams varchar2, outParams out nocopy varchar2);
    procedure proc3 (inParams varchar2, outParams out nocopy varchar2);
 end myProcedures;
/
create or replace package body myProcedures as
    procedure execute is
        inParams varchar2(32000);
        outParams varchar2(32000);
    begin
        for r in (
            select *
            from user_procedures
            where object_name = upper('myProcedures') 
            and   object_type = 'PACKAGE' 
            and   subprogram_id > 1
            order by subprogram_id
            ) loop
            inParams := lower(r.object_name||'.'||r.procedure_name)||
                '(objId='||r.object_id||':procId='||r.subprogram_id||')';
            execute immediate 
            'begin '||
                r.object_name||'.'||r.procedure_name||'(:inParams, :outParams);'||
            'end;' using in inParams, out outParams;
            dbms_output.put_linе (outParams);
        end loop;
    end execute;    
    procedure proc1 (inParams varchar2, outParams out nocopy varchar2) is
    begin outParams := inParams||' executed ret=0'; end proc1;
    procedure proc2 (inParams varchar2, outParams out nocopy varchar2) is
    begin outParams := inParams||' executed ret=0'; end proc2;
    procedure proc3 (inParams varchar2, outParams out nocopy varchar2) is
    begin outParams := inParams||' executed ret=0'; end proc3;
end myProcedures;
/
```

Запустить и получить вывод:

```
exec myProcedures.execute 

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

myprocedures.proc1(objId=178418:procId=2) executed ret=0
myprocedures.proc2(objId=178418:procId=3) executed ret=0
myprocedures.proc3(objId=178418:procId=4) executed ret=0
```

Comment: Cпасибо, Я сосредоточился на вашем примере и получил результат

Comment: Пожалуйста! Если бы вы доработали вопрос, чтобы он более точно  описывал вашу задачу, то вы смогли бы ещё и репутации заработать. Зачем там, например безконечный цикл, или где объявленa `PRODCEDURE`?

Comment: PAKET_NAME имя пакета

Answer (score 0):

```css
create or replace package body UT3_SUITE_TOTAL as
    
procedure DP_SUITE_TOTAL is
 begin
      for r in (
  select *
          from user_procedures
          where object_name in ('PAKET_NAME') 
          and   object_type  = 'PACKAGE'
          and   subprogram_id > 1
          order by subprogram_id
                ) 
      loop
          execute immediate 
          'begin '||
                r.object_name||'.'||r.procedure_name||';'||
          'end;';
      end loop;
 end DP_SUITE_TOTAL;    

end UT3_SUITE_TOTAL;
```

```css
create or replace package UT3_SUITE_TOTAL as
  -- %suite
  -- %test
  procedure DP_SUITE_TOTAL;      
  end UT3_SUITE_TOTAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, вы юнит-тесты пишете. Тогда возьмите какой-нибудь фреймворк - например, [utPLSQL](http://utplsql.org/).

Я в свое время тоже пилил свой собственный фреймворк и даже допилил до более-менее работоспособного состояния (на предыдущей работе использовал), но он не документирован совсем, и я к нему года 3 или 4 вообще не прикасался. Хотя если кому интересно, могу дать ссылку.